# SQL for returning objects based on exact input and count

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

Table1

```
Col1             Col2
Committee name   Count of Employees
```

And 
Table2

```
Col1             Col2
Committee name   Employee name
```

I want to find the committee which matches the count of Employees and the given employee names

For e.g. i have these committees with given employees
My input is EmpA, EmpB, EmpC and EmpD
I am expecting only Cultural committee to be returned

```
Working Committee
EmpX
EmpY
EmpA
EmpB

Sports Committee
EmpM
EmpN
EmpA

Finance Committee
EmpA
EmpB
EmpC
EmpD
EmpE

Cultural committee
EmpA
EmpB
EmpC
EmpD
```

Struggling with writing an SQL which takes input as example EmpM, EmpN, EmpA, EmpB, EmpC, EmpD and the count as 3 and 4. Output expected is Sports Committee(M,N,A) and Cultural Committee(A,B,C,D).

Thanks,
Pavan

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select committee_name
from table2
group by committee_name
having sum(case when employee_name in ('EmpA', 'EmpB', 'EmpC', 'EmpD') then 1 else 0 end) = count(*);
```

This formulation assumes that `table2` has no duplicates.

Comment: Table2 column 1 is unique but employees are shared. The input is a list of employees and I am not sure if the count is also to be provided as input as I want committee names to which input employees belong and also match the exact count

Comment: @PavanMirji . . . This matches the count for the numbers listed in the table.  Assuming the first and second tables are in synch, the first is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using subquery:

```
select count(*), t1.CommitteeName
from table2 t1
where t1.EmployeeName in ('EmpM', 'EmpN', 'EmpA', 'EmpB', 'EmpC', 'EmpD')
group by t1.CommitteeName
having count(*) =
(
select t2.CountOfEmployees
from table1 t2
where t2.CommitteeName = t1.CommitteeName
```